# Apache Kafka - Consumer not receiving messages from producer

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I would appreciate your help on this.

I am building a Apache Kafka consumer to subscribe to another already running Kafka. Now, my problem is that when my producer pushes message to server...my consumer does not receive them .. and I get the below info in my logs printed::

```
13/08/30 18:00:58 INFO producer.SyncProducer: Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx:6667:false for producing
13/08/30 18:00:58 INFO producer.SyncProducer: Disconnecting from xx.xx.xx.xx:6667:false
13/08/30 18:00:58 INFO consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager: [ConsumerFetcherManager-     1377910855898] Stopping leader finder thread
13/08/30 18:00:58 INFO consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager: [ConsumerFetcherManager-    1377910855898] Stopping all fetchers 
13/08/30 18:00:58 INFO consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager: [ConsumerFetcherManager- 1377910855898] All connections stopped
```

I am not sure if I am missing any important configuration here...However, I can see some messages coming from my server using WireShark but they are not getting consumed by my consumer....

My code is the exact replica of the sample consumer example:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

**UPDATE:**

```
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,146] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread.     
(org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,146] INFO Opening socket connection to server /xx.xx.xx.xx:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,235] INFO Connected to xx.xx.xx:6667 for producing (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,299] INFO Socket connection established to 10.224.62.212/10.224.62.212:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,399] INFO Disconnecting from xx.xx.xx.net:6667 (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,400] INFO [ConsumerFetcherManager-1378195030845] Stopping leader finder thread (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,400] INFO [ConsumerFetcherManager-1378195030845] Stopping all fetchers (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,400] INFO [ConsumerFetcherManager-1378195030845] All connections stopped (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,400] INFO [console-consumer-49997_xx.xx.xx-1378195030443-cce6fc51],    Cleared all relevant queues for this fetcher (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,400] INFO [console-consumer-49997_xx.xx.xx.-1378195030443-cce6fc51], Cleared the data chunks in all the consumer message iterators (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,400] INFO [console-consumer-49997_xx.xx.xx.xx-1378195030443-cce6fc51], Committing all offsets after clearing the fetcher queues (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,401] ERROR [console-consumer-49997_xx.xx.xx.xx-1378195030443-cce6fc51], zk client is null. Cannot commit offsets (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,401] INFO [console-consumer-49997_xx.xx.xx.xx-1378195030443-cce6fc51], Releasing partition ownership (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
[2013-09-03 00:57:30,401] INFO [console-consumer-49997_xx.xx.xx.xx-1378195030443-cce6fc51], exception during rebalance  (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:185)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:183)
at    kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$rebalance$2.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:434)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$rebalance$2.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:429)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:80)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:80)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:631)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:161)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:194)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:80)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$rebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:429)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:374)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range$ByOne$class.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:282)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range$$anon$2.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:265)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:369)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:681)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$WildcardStreamsHandler.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:715)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreamsByFilter(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:140)
at kafka.consumer.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:196)
at kafka.consumer.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide your producer code sample?

Do you have the latest 0.8 version checked out? It appears that there has been some known issue with [consumerFetched deadlock](http://www.mail-archive.com/commits@kafka.apache.org/msg00492.html) which has been patched and fixed in the current version

you can try to use the admin console script to consume messages making sure your producer is working fine.

If possible post some more logs and code snippet, should help debugging further
(it seems I need more reputation to make a comment so had to answer instead)

Comment: Thanks for responding...What logs do you need specifically. Also, where can I find the admin console script to check my producer...I guess that my producer is working because I can see some messages coming from my server using WireShark at the consumer terminal.

Comment: The console script can be found inside your `KAFKA_DIR/bin` path .. and [here](http://kafka.apache.org/08/quickstart.html) some example command to get you started, how your producer code looks like ?

Comment: Thanks for responding again... I tried your way of using a consumer console script..However, when I try connecting to my server I get a below exception trace printed on the console...I have updated my question with the exception trace..some sort of rebalancing .. i dnt understand..

Comment: Which version of Kafka are you using? Can you do the following .. create a topic using the console producer ,produce some message with the topic and then try to consume the same using the console script and see if that is working . .also is the version same at both producer, consumer end?